# reprepro No section given for 'galera', skipping

Tags: repository, reprepro

I'm trying to create a local repository using `reprepro`. Below are the steps and folder structure.

I have created a directory name `my_repo`. Directory Structure:

```
my_repo/
conf/
     --> distributions
     --> override
     --> override.precise.extra.main
     --> override.precise.main
     --> override.precise.main.debian-installer

distributions
----------------------
Origin: Ubuntu
Label: Ubuntu
Codename: precise
Suite: stable
Version: 12.04
Architectures: amd64 i386
Components: main
DebOverride: override
UDebComponents: main
Description: GUI-Installer cd mirror
SignWith: yes
Pull: precise
```

Then I gave the command below to add the debian:

```
`reprepro -V -b my_repo/ -C main includedeb precise galera_23.2.2_amd64.deb`
```

Then it is failing to add the debian by giving the error below:

> No section given for 'galera', skipping.

Any pointers on this will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override the section with `-S`:

```
`reprepro -V -b my_repo/ -S utils -C main includedeb precise galera_23.2.2_amd64.deb`
```

Comment: Hi Sylvain i have added Section and Priority parameters to override file. It worked for me. I have done this because i'm having couple of packages with the similar error. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: can you please tell me how to accept in this forum Sylvain

Comment: Below the (^) 0 (v) marks you should have a greyed checkbox, just click on it to accept the answer, it will be green then. Thanks

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers